# Form not sending data to database

Tags: php, html

My form for collecting visitors' mails for newsletter is not sending information to my database, instead just adding spaces with index adding up with no data
this is my html code

```html
<form action="php/newsletter.php" method="post" >
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="email"  name="email" placeholder="E-mail ... ">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary subscribe" type="button" value="insert"><i class="pe-7s-paper-plane pe-2x"></i></button>
            </span>
     </div>
     <!-- /input-group -->
</form>
```

and this is the php

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "pridedri_news";
$password = "BBIT/7949/1/1630";
$database = "pridedri_NEWSLETTER";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers (email)
    VALUES ('$email')";
    
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    
    echo "Request sent successfully";
     
    } catch(PDOException $e) {    
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    
    
//$conn = null; 

?>

<Doctype! html>
<body>

    <a href="http://pridedrivetours.co.ke/">Back</>
</body>

</html>
```

where could my mistake be?

Comment: Where's your `$email` variable defined?

Comment: You use PDO, but why not prepared statements?

Comment: _“where could my mistake be?”_ - you did not read up on the very basics of how to process form data with PHP, so please go do that now ...

Comment: Thanks alot i got it

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined `$email` in your PHP script. Also, you should use a prepared statement for queries with user inputs, to prevent SQL injection (http://bobby-tables.com) -> This is kinda important, please read about SQL injection. Its one of the biggest security issues with PHP websites and it allows 3rd persons to delete your whole database in a few seconds.

Also, to access data posted from a form, you always access the `$_POST` array, while the key `["email"]` is the name of the input.

Try this code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "pridedri_news";
$password = "BBIT/7949/1/1630";
$database = "pridedri_NEWSLETTER";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO subscribers (email) VALUES (:email)");
    $sql->bindParam(':email', $_POST["email"]);

    // even exec() returnes true or false!!!!
    if($conn->exec($sql)) {     
        echo "Request sent successfully";
    }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {    
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


//$conn = null; 

?>

<Doctype! html>
<body>

<a href="http://pridedrivetours.co.ke/">Back</>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare $email before using it in mysql query

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
```

I hope it will work for you

Comment: It would work, but its a bad solution. He would still be at a high risk of SQL injection.

Comment: you should use a prepared statement for queries to prevent sql injection like this     $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO subscribers (email) VALUES ($_POST["email"]);